# How to hide image's alt tag when you reload the page with lazyload?

Tags: html, css, lazy-loading

I am using lazyload to display my images in my website (with data-src instead of src).

However, when you reload the page, you can see the alt tag appear (during 0.1s during the loading).
I saw some similar questions, but not exactly helpful because nothing works for me, for example like this class:

```
 img:-moz-loading {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

There is a way to hide the alt tag and the little picture [image] (without removing the tag) during the reload of the page ?

The alt tag should only appear if the image doesn't exist at the end of the load

Thank you,

Comment: You could try using the NgIf directive https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf  and then create a loading variable to assign boolean to based on when your content is done loading. Just a thought

Comment: A common technique is to hide it as the default style and then display it once it's loaded.

Comment: How do you know when it's loaded ? Thanks for you answers, i will try ngif

Comment: It works perfectly with ng-if. Thank you. But for my part, it seems to be a bad practice to use that

Comment: Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166235/firefox-alt-text-appears-while-loading-image