# Firefox alt text appears while loading image

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, alt

On **Firefox** if you refresh a page you'll see the alt text appearing while an image is loading.

You can see it just on [this Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images?retiredLocale=it) (check the first image).

This doesn't happen on Chrome and other modern browsers.

I find an [old issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1472637) on Bugzilla but it results as Fixed.

On that topic I find this pseudo solution (also here on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399798/1252920))

```
img:-moz-loading {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

that works very well **but** as says the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-loading) it's *non-standard*:

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
> track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
> work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Any solutions?

Notice: I won't consider solutions like `color: transparent` or similar, that hide the alt text to users, as it's needed.

Comment: I have the same issue... I'm using the latest firefox browser 91.0.2 (64-bits)
When I use the refresh button, I see the alt text of the images

Comment: @keno have you found a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @FredK Still no solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `onload` and `onerror` to reset the color of the alt text when it's needed:

```html
<img style="color: transparent;" onload="this.style.color='black'" onerror="this.style.color='black'" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="Alternate text" />
```

Comment: I prefer to use `"this.style.color='unset'"` to simply revert to the previous color, that way you don't have to hardcode an specific color like black.